# Getting Observable value is not working ?

Tags: knockout.js

I am using `knockout.js` library. I have a Boolean value and I am saving it as Observable. But when I try to get  the value in a drop down selected index change event. It gives me this error :

`Object function viewModel(model) {

        this.stocks = ko.observableArray(model.stocks);
        this.isGeneral = ko.observable(model.generalStockEnabled);
    } has no method 'isGeneral'`

Here is my code for registering my model :

```
 function viewModel(model) {      
        this.stocks = ko.observableArray(model.stocks);
        this.isGeneral = ko.observable(model.generalStockEnabled);
    }
```

here is my drop down list event :

```
 $('#enableGeneratInventorydl').change(function () {
            if ($('#enableGeneratInventorydl :selected').val() === "True")
            {
                alert(viewModel.isGeneral())

            }
            else
            {

            }
        });
```

I am calling this at page initialize

```
 ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(data));
```

the data object has a boolean value generalStockEnabled.

Any Idea ?

Comment: `viewModel` is just the constructor and does not refer to the object created by `new viewModel(data)`. You should assign created object to a variable first, and then use it to call its members: `var vm = new vieeModel(data); alert(vm.isGeneral());`

Comment: should i do this :  ko.applyBindings(vm) in this case ?

Comment: If you're using knockout you really shouldn't be using jquery to listen to events and react to them like that. You should be binding to your dropdownbox, or subscribing to your observable.

Comment: @wasatz using subscribe is better than listening to jquerey events, or because it is a core feature of knockout ? sorry for my question if is it simple but i started using knockout 5 hrs ago.

Comment: @Mohammadjouhari Yes. The reason here is that you are most likely interested in the changes in your _viewmodel_ and what you're doing in jquery there alerts you of changes to your _view_. Using ko instead you can react to changes even when your viewmodel is not actively being shown in the view and you don't need to refer to element id's in your javascript code which makes it easier to test and refactor.

Comment: @wasatz I started using your suggestions. After I went through the library, I realized that data binding is more efficient and easier to handle. Thank you very much for your suggestion and co-operation.

Comment: Glad to be of help, good luck with knockout! It's really a fantastic library when you get used to thinking the mvvm way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create global variable `viewModel` and this will works well:

```
function viewModel(model) 
{      
   this.stocks = ko.observableArray(model.stocks);
   this.isGeneral = ko.observable(model.generalStockEnabled);
}
window.myViewModel = new viewModel(data);  
//...  
ko.applyBindings(window.myViewModel);
```

Now you can call `myViewModel.isGeneral()` anywhere

```
$('#enableGeneratInventorydl').change(function () 
      {
        if ($('#enableGeneratInventorydl :selected').val() === "True")
        {
            alert(myViewModel.isGeneral())
// ...
```